# Ubuntu vhost config - restrict public access from subdomain root

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I have set up a subdomain for my SSO / SAML configuration via SimpleSAML. As the admin, all the files that I (or anyone else) will really need access to are in the https://sso.domain.com/www/ folder, which is why I set a restriction in the `sso.domain.com.conf` vhost configuration file. The problem is that this does not seem to work and the root of the subdomain still wide open for everyone to see.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sso.domain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sso

    SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR /var/www/html/sso/config
    Alias /simplesaml /var/www/html/sso/www

    <Directory /var/www/html/sso/www>
         Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sso.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

How do I configure the above conf file to only allow public access to the /www/ subfolder and not the root of the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use `/var/www/html/sso` as your DocumentRoot** in the first place. Apache shouldn't be serving that location *at all.* It contains PHP files, yes, but those will be loaded via PHP's require() without involving Apache.

(And it also contains your IdP private key, so putting all of that in the public access area and then trying to restrict that access again is a recipe for fatal mistakes.)

So instead, point DocumentRoot either at an unrelated directory that just contains an index.html (e.g. /var/www/misc), *or* point it directly at the /var/www/html/sso/www subdirectory (won't need the Alias anymore).

Personally I would even move the entire SimpleSAMLphp installation *out of* /var/www, so that it wouldn't be affected by your distro's default `<Directory /var/www>` configuration, reducing the risk of accidentally exposing those files through another VirtualHost. For example, I might put it in /srv or /usr/lib:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sso.example.com

    # No need for 'DocumentRoot' or 'Alias' in a redirect-only vhost

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L,NE]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sso.example.com
    (...log settings, SSL settings, PHP-FPM settings...)

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /simplesaml /srv/simplesamlphp/www

    <Directory /srv/simplesamlphp/www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```